# Lightning Pop-Out Utility and LDS

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a custom aura component to be used as a pop out in the utility bar in a console app. LDS (`force:recordData`) is being used to query the record details:

```
<force:recordData aura:id="LDS"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    fields="{!v.objFields}"
    targetFields="{!v.myRecord}"
    targetError="{!v.objError}"
    mode="EDIT"
    recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
/>
```

I am detecting the recordId change:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.recordId}" action="{!c.handleIdChange}"/>
```

and reloading via

```
handleIdChange: function(component){
    component.find("recordLoader").reloadRecord();
}
```

This all works fine, so when the primary tab changes the pop out updates to reflect the new record Id. However when the component has been open as a pop out LDS no longer detects changes to the record via other component - i.e. `handleRecordUpdated` does not get called.

It works as expected while still docked.

Is there a way to get a pop out utility component to reload when the record is changed via another component?

Comment: Have you tried firing an application event via the non-pop-out component, and triggering pop-out component LDS reload via that event?